# Nodejs Pagination Issue with skiping documents not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pagination

I created a simple API to fetch a list of data from MongoDB. I also added the pagination in case the document grows to manage the data in multiple data throughout pages. However, I am facing the issue of document skipping when I use the `pageSize` value to 2 or 3 (but it works on 5 currently have 7 documents in total) in the list it only skips one document when I go through the one-by-one pages I see that some of the documents are not showing in the list. Here is the code. Please comment if you need more info.

```
export const getSchemesList = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { pageSize, pageNumber, status } = req.query;

        const page = Number(pageNumber) || 1;
        const sort = { created_at: -1 };
        let query = {};

        if (status) {
            query.status = status;
        }

        const count = await Scheme.countDocuments(query);
        const skipDoc = pageSize * (page - 1);
        const pages = Math.ceil(count / pageSize);

        let schemes;
        if (status) {
            schemes = await Scheme.find(query).sort(sort).limit(pageSize).skip(skipDoc);
        } else {
            schemes = await Scheme.find().sort(sort).limit(pageSize).skip(skipDoc);
        }

        res.json({ schemes, page, pages });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500);
        throw new Error({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you try to skip before the limit since need to skip the first 2 items and then get 2 items after skipping, like; await Scheme.find(query).sort(sort).skip(skipDoc).limit(pageSize);

Comment: @OnurDoğan I tried just now but didn't work.

Comment: @NarayanMaity I agree with Onur, the order of the skip and limit is important. But also, you may want to make sure that pageSize is a number, and convert it with a default value `(Number(pagesize) || 5)`. I guess you could debug it by adding the req to the res.json to verify the params. Just to make sure those are correct. Because your code looks fine imho.

Comment: @bvdb as you agreed with Onur and I also use your advice and checked the type of `pageSize` which is showing me string then i created a constant variable and converted the `pageSize`  type to number but still the problem is same I don't know why is this happening I also use both method before skip and limit and limit and skip in both condition the answer was same. Kindly please look into this

Comment: @bvbd Thank you to replying I found out the problem is with sorting when I remove the sort it worked as expected then again I added the sorting after limit and skip then I see the problem started again after certain time then i added the sorting in next line after the if/else block like this `schemes = schemes.sort((a, b) => b.created_at - a.created_at)` then I noticed that pagination is working but the sorting is not so I checked my schema then I realize I never added the timestamp field so there is no such field called created_at because of this I spent days to figure out why its not working

Comment: @OnurDoğan thank you too for replying because of my silly mistake I spent days to figuring out why its not working.

Comment: @NarayanMaity happens to all of us. The important thing is that you managed to narrow it down, which ultimately helped you to find the bug. - Perhaps a good idea to answer your own question below for future visitors of this page, who may have similar issues. - Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem or the bug with the help of @bvdb and @OnurDoğan. The problem is with my sorting  `const sort = { created_at: -1 };` I used this line to sort my response data but the issue is I never added the `timestamp` field in the schema so there is no variable called `createdAt`.